# c# equal strings not considered equal

Tags: c#, string, hex, monotorrent

I have problem with monotorrent in C#. It drop peers, because the peer's ID in the handshake is not equal to the given tracker.

The problematic code block looks like this:

```
    if (id.Peer.PeerId != message.PeerId)
    {
        Logger.Log(id.Connection, "HandShake.Handle - Invalid peerid");

        //Here is my debug:

        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(id.Peer.PeerId));
        Console.WriteLine("1: {0}", hex);
        string hex1 = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message.PeerId));
        Console.WriteLine("2: {0}", hex1);
        if (hex == hex1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hex eq");
        }
        if (id.Peer.PeerId.Equals(message.PeerId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("string eq");
        }
        throw new TorrentException("Supplied PeerID didn't match the one the tracker gave us");
    }
```

It returns something like this:

```
1: 2D-42-54-37-39-32-30-2D-78-3F-3F-3F-12-4C-24-3F-71-3F-3E-68
2: 2D-42-54-37-39-32-30-2D-78-3F-3F-3F-12-4C-24-3F-71-3F-3E-68
hex eq
1: 2D-42-54-37-39-32-30-2D-78-3F-3F-3F-12-4C-24-3F-71-3F-3E-68
2: 2D-42-54-37-39-32-30-2D-78-3F-3F-3F-12-4C-24-3F-71-3F-3E-68
hex eq
```

Why are strings, which are fully identical in hex, not considered equal?

**Update:** The tracker returns response to announce request (get peers) encoded in CP1251. Could this cause a problem?

**Update2:**
I think the reason is som encoding flags. I added this:

```
            var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(id.Peer.PeerId));
            var str1 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message.PeerId));

            if (id.Peer.PeerId.Equals(message.PeerId))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("string eq");
            }
            if (str.Equals(str1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("str eq str1");
            }
```

and got this:

```
1: 2D-55-54-33-34-32-30-2D-7E-7D-01-4B-3F-79-3F-3F-3F-1A-73-3F
2: 2D-55-54-33-34-32-30-2D-7E-7D-01-4B-3F-79-3F-3F-3F-1A-73-3F
hex eq
str eq str1
1: 2D-55-54-33-33-32-30-2D-5F-76-11-3F-3F-6E-3F-0A-3F-54-62-3F
2: 2D-55-54-33-33-32-30-2D-5F-76-11-3F-3F-6E-3F-0A-3F-54-62-3F
hex eq
str eq str1
```

very interesting!

Comment: What is the PeerId type? Is it byte array? You can't compare byte array directly!

Comment: id.Peer.PeerId and message.PeerId are strings

Comment: If `PeerId`s are a strings and they are equal, if-block will never be executed. So It is not posssible for us to regenerate your case. (BTW: if they are not equal, then there is no meaning in using BitConverter and Encoding)

Comment: the only way for this happen that I can think of is if `id.Peer.PeerId` were a `char[]` instead of a `string`.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to string comparison, I always use Trim() both Strings and use String.Equals() Method. If the comparison is not case sensitive, then I also use ToLower() method, before the comparison starts.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t4411bks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
Boolean StringsAreEqual = String.Equals(String1.Trim().ToLower(), String2.Trim().ToLower(), ...)
```

Comment: If leading/trailing spaces and lower/upper case was the case, the hex code would have been different.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following construction to compare strings in C#:

```
if(String.Compare(id.Peer.PeerId, message.PeerId, StringComparison. InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != 0) 
{ 

    // strings as different
}
```

You can switch the `StringComparison` as you need.
Take a look at these options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: if (String.Compare(id.Peer.PeerId, message.PeerId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("String.Compare equal!");
                }  -- not works :(

Comment: No, it is written `!=`, not `==`.

Comment: Yes, i see, but i check that strings are equal, not different